# Why is a const variable available within a static method?

Tags: .net, static, language-design, constants

I have been writing code without realizing WHY I can access constant values within static 
methods.

Why is it possible to access `const` values without declaring it as `static`?

E.g.) It's legal to call `IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION` within `AddImageToDocument(...)`

```
public abstract class ImageDocumentReplacer : DocumentReplacer
{
    private const string IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION = ".tif";

    private static void AddImageToDocument(int documentId, string separatedPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`const` members are implicitly `static`. They belong to the class rather than a specific instance. As a consequence, you can't use `this.myConstant` but `MyClass.myConstant`.

Quoting the C# 3.0 specification (section §10.4 Constants):

> Even though **constants are considered `static` members**, a *constant-declaration* **neither requires nor allows** a `static` modifier. It is an error for the same modifier to appear multiple times in a constant declaration.

Comment: Just adding: Try using static const, and your compiler will probably complain ;)

Comment: @Samuel : Yes, siree it does!

Comment: I never thought of const being *implicitly* static... Thanks Mehrdad.

Answer (score 2):

Why should it not be possible? Since the value is fixed at compile time, there is no possible inconsistency (as there would be with variables or `readonly` fields that can be initialized to different values for different instances at runtime)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that, since a constant can't change instance-to-instance, that makes them safe to access from a static method.